# How to exclude a view from the master layout?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a master layout in my Laravel 4 app: /views/layouts/main.blade.php
and I need to exclude it from a single view: /views/users/login.blade.php

My master layout is a complete bootstrap admin layout with menus and all, instead I want to use a separate layout for the login page that only shows the login form and nothing else.

How may I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming the opposite of zwacky's answer, if you are extending master, can't you just remove it?

Answer (score 3):

i'm assuming, you're including somewhere in your main.blade.php template the login.blade.php.
why not passing a variable to the `View::make()` that determines, whether login.blade.php should be shown or not?

`@if ($showLogin)
    @include('useres.login')
@endif`

you could then also use `Request::is('admin/*')` if the login should only be visible on certain routes.

reference: [laravel request information](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information)

Answer (score 0):

You should have login.blade.php extend another layout. For example in my app, i have 2 layouts (so far). One for the main app (admin panel) and one for the login, create account, forgot password etc. pages.